# Problem extracting xml text with Erlang xmerl_xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, erlang

I'm trying to extract text from an xml node using Erlang's `xmerl_xpath`:

```
[include "xmerl.hrl"]

{Doc, _}=xmerl_scan:string("<node>Hello World</node>").

[#xmlText{value=Text}]=xmerl_xpath:string("//node/text()", Doc).

Text.

"Hello World"
```

Works fine for this simple example. Problem occurs when the text in the node element is very large, say 1MB; xmerl_scan:string works fine [ie the document parses okay], but trying to extract the text produces this error:

```
{{badmatch,[{xmlText,[{node,1}],1,[],"[large text here]"}]}}
```

I thought maybe

a) xmerl_scan:string produces a different document structure when the text size is very large

b) I've reached some kind of limit for the Erlang string length

Any ideas what might be happening ?

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you ask a question where some error pops up, please provide the error listing

Comment: Could you provide an example of these xml strings that cause the error?

Comment: Really need to see (a) the xml and (b) the pattern you're trying to match. 1Mb isn't that large.

Comment: (c) optionally the return value of the call to xmerl_scan:string() :)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same error message and I think the problem is caused by not correctly matching what `xmerl_xpath:string()` returns, e.g. it returns a list of `docEntity()` things, in this case they're all `#xmlText{}` records. I fixed it by extracting all the string values from the `#xmlText{}` records and then concatenating the list using `lists:concat`.

So this:

```
[#xmlText{value=Text}]=xmerl_xpath:string("//node/text()", Doc)
```

just matches exactly one `#xmlText` while with a long string you would probably get multiple `#xmlText` records. This may be because the XML parser parses a long string into multiple text nodes.

This will work better I think:

```
Text = lists:concat(map(fun(XmlText) -> #xmlText{value=TextValue} = XmlText, TextValue end, xmerl_xpath:string("//node/text()", Doc)))
```

Comment: A related thing to be careful about, especially when testing from the shell, is not to have the variable Text already be bound.
If it's already bound (to a different text string than what the search returns), then that'd give the same symptoms.

Comment: There's a typo, map() should be lists:map(), as in: Text = lists:concat(lists:map(fun(XmlText) -> #xmlText{value=TextValue} = XmlText, TextValue end, xmerl_xpath:string("//node/text()", Doc)))

Answer (score 1):

What was your actual error? I don't really see how this could be the cause, but Erlang strings do [take a lot of space](http://schemecookbook.org/Erlang/StringBasics); the integer list implementation takes 8 bytes of memory per character.

Comment: Error as follows:

{{badmatch,[{xmlText,[{node,1}],1,[],"[large text here]"}]}}

Comment: If it was a memory problem, loading the module itself would fail, wouldn't it?